# Writing a Script to Kill a Process for a User?

Tags: ubuntu

- List the running processes for that user.
- Confirm with the system administrator before killing the processes.
- Kill the processes after confirmation.

Comment: welcome to the site again, this site isn't for writing scripts, we here to help you if something wrong happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to list all the running processes, use `ps`:

```
ps –aux (list all process) 

ps –aux |grep processName

top (something like task manager) (don’t use it with scripting)
```

to kill any process:

```
kill -9 processNumber
```

as a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
ps -aux
do
echo "enter the processNum you want to kill?"
read num
echo "Are you sure you want to kill $num?"
echo "write 1  if yes"
echo "write 2 if No "
read choice
if [ $choice -eq 1 ]
then
kill -9 $num
fi
done
```